# .live() and .data()

Tags: jquery, live

I'm trying to make a piece of JavaScript that allows me to just add an `<input>` with a certain class, and it will automatically add placeholder-like behaviour to it. The problem is, I load some inputs in via AJAX. I use the `.live()` method to get around this, however `.data()` doesn't want to play.

Here's an example:

#### jQuery

```
$(".placeHolder").data("originalValue", $(this).val());

$(".placeHolder").live("focus", function() {
    if($(this).val() == $(this).data("originalValue"))
    {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
$(".placeHolder").live("blur", function() {
    if(!$(this).val().length)
    {
        $(this).val($(this).data("originalValue"));
    }
});

// Load inputs into an element
$("selector").load("loadInput.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
    $(".placeHolder").data("originalValue", $(this).val());
});
```

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="Bar" class="placeHolder">
```

The problem is the fact that the `<input>`'s original value isn't stored by `.data()` anywhere - even in the `.post()` call. There can be more than one `.placeHolder` on the page.

Am I using `.data()` incorrectly? If not, what else is going wrong?

Comment: I assume `selector` is just psudo code?

Comment: @Joseph: Of course. I just gave it as an example selector.

Comment: You need to give us the code in context. As shown, the very first line would lead to your issue as `this` references `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.live()` places an event handler on the `document` element, which uses event bubbling to catch events, and checks if they come from an appropriate source. `.data()` attaches data to an existing element. You're using `live()` because you load your data via AJAX, and it will work regardless of when your `<input>` elements appear. But `data()` doesn't work that way.

If you are using a recent enough version of jQuery, you may be able to use HTML5 `data-` attributes and access them using the `data()` handler.

Comment: I'd like to use HTML 5 `data` attributes, however this site needs to work on at least IE 7. Do browsers this old (and in the case of IE, crap) support data attributes _via jQuery_?

Comment: I believe so. Pretty much all browsers preserve custom attributes, so they should work everywhere. Test it to be sure.

Comment: I can only go down to IE 7 (in IE 8), but if you or anyone else could test a JSFiddle in IE 6 or something, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

@JAAulde has a point...

```
$(".placeHolder").data("originalValue", $(this).val());
```

Should be this maybe?

```
$(".placeHolder").each(function(){
  $(this).data("originalValue", $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much Joseph! Just as a quick aside, is there a way to do this once at the beginning of the document, instead of every time I do an AJAX call, or modify the DOM?

Comment: +1 Ha, wow, I just thought he was giving us pseudo code out of context. Glad you went further with my comment and provided a valid answer!

Comment: @JamWaffles lol I just tried it and ran into an infinite loop XD but basically I can't see another way to do it other than adding a DOMNodeInserted event in the document. `$(document.body).bind("DOMNodeInserted",function(){...})`. My problem was that (as test data) I was appending text to a node... this triggered the event and resulted in an infinite loops, but simply modifying the data of an object would be ok. :P

Comment: @JAAulde I know XD I thought similar intil you pointed it out :P

Comment: Maybe a slightly sub optimal solution? Although infinite loops do have their place in web development ;-P Thanks for your help Joseph.